# Evaluate the double integral $\iint_D\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ bounded by semi-circle

Tags: calculus, integration, circles

I would appreciate it if someone can help me solve this question, as I'm struggling to get its answer.

Q: Evaluate the double integral $$\iint_D\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}dxdy$$ bounded by semi-circle $$x^2+y^2=2x$$ and lying in first quadrant

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using polar coordinates, $x^2+y^2=2x$ gives $r^2=2r\cos\theta$ so $r=2\cos\theta$.

For the part of the region inside the circle which is also in the first quadrant, we get

$\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2\cos\theta}\sqrt{4-r^2}\; r\;drd\theta=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left[-\frac{1}{3}(4-r^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{r=0}^{r=2\cos\theta}d\theta=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{8}{3}(1-\sin^3\theta)d\theta$

$\displaystyle=\frac{8}{3}\left[\theta+\cos\theta-\frac{1}{3}\cos^3\theta\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\frac{8}{3}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{4}{9}\left(3\pi-4\right)$

Comment: Yup I guess your answer is the better one, thanks mate

Comment: Why is the upper limit on the value of theta taken as pi/2? Why not pi ?

Comment: @SwarnavaChandraBose If you look at the answer below, you notice that $0 \le x \le 2$ implies that we're in the first quadrant, hence $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

We have: $$x^2+y^2=2x$$

Moving everything to the left: $$x^2-2x+y^2=0$$

Completing the square: $$(x-1)^2+y^2=1$$

Which is a circle with centre $(1,0)$, hence: $$0\le x\le2$$

Solving $y$: $$y=\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}$$

So the integral becomes: $$\int_{x=0}^{x=2}\int_{y=0}^{y=\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}\ \mathrm dy\ \mathrm dx$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Kenny Lau
but I didn't quite get your 6th line, could u elaborate please?
edit: the one after the word (Also:)

Comment: Oh, that is just straight applying $x^2+y^2=2x$.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I meant the one after the word (Also: )
that would be the 12th line

Comment: Yes, that is just straight applying $x^2+y^2=2x$.

Comment: If you want one more step: $$\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}=\sqrt{4-(x^2+y^2)}=\sqrt{4-(2x)}$$

Comment: oh, I feel stupid now, well thanks very much, I appreciate you taking your time to answer me

Comment: Glad you find it helpful.

Comment: Is this equality valid? I mean, $$\sqrt (4-x^2-y^2)=\sqrt(4-2x)$$. This is valid when the point is on the circle side boundary. But it is not when it is inside the circle.